# Using 96-hour transit visa for Dubai from India

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, dubai

I am travelling with family to Dubai from Bangalore (India) on 20th December for 3 days and coming back to Amritsar (India) on 23rd December.

Can I get a 96-hour transit visa? If not then which visa (cheapest one) should I go for?

Comment: No. 96h possible only if onward journey to Europe/UK/USA etc. You can apply for 14 day visa: http://www.dubaivisa.net/india/know_your_visa_type.html

Answer (score 11):

[You cannot get a 96-hour transit visa](http://www.emirates247.com/news/emirates/96-hour-transit-visa-for-all-airline-passengers-at-uae-airports-2015-09-20-1.604073), because you are returning directly to India. You're visiting Dubai, not transiting it:

> According to an email from Amer Contact Center, a passenger can apply
>   for a transit 96 hours visa at the airport upon paying its fees.
>   However, they have to meet certain conditions such as the duration
>   between the two trips should not be less than 8 hours and the two
>   trips should be to different destinations (one should transit from
>   Dubai to another destination and not back to the same place where
>   he/she came from.)

[The Emirates airline website](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/) explains the requirements. There's a special provision if you hold a valid US visa:

> As of 1 May 2017, Indian nationals holding a normal passport valid for
>   a minimum of six months from the arrival date, and a visit visa or
>   green card issued by the USA which is valid for a minimum of six
>   months, can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 14 days for
>   a charge of AED120 (subject to change). They can apply to extend their
>   stay for an additional 14 days for AED250 (subject to change).

If you don't qualify for that, you'll need to apply for a visa in advance. This must be arranged through your airline (e.g. [Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/), [flydubai](https://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/visas-and-passports/uae-visas)), hotel, or travel agent. You should apply for the type of visa appropriate for your visit (business, tourism, etc...). If you're traveling for tourism, a short-term tourist visa would make sense.